# Homestead - No Input File Specified

Tags: homestead

I am new to using Homestead/Vagrant.
I have read as much as I can, but still can't understand what am I doing wrong.
When I try and access my site in my browser I am getting "No Input File Specified". To keep things simple, I have placed a simple `index.php` file at the following location: "C:\Code\php_projects\TestFolder\TestProject\public"

My Homestead.yaml file:

```yaml
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
folders:
    - map: /home/vagrant/Code/php_projects/TestFolder     
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
sites:
    - map: homestead.test
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/php_projects/TestFolder/TestProject/public
```

I have added the following to my local "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts" file:

```
192.168.10.10  homestead.test
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing folders to:

folders:
    - map: ~/Code

This fixed my issue.

Comment: uping because it forced me to ["debug it" with my rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).